# HTML5 server-sent event on IE?

Tags: php, jquery, html, server-sent-events

do IE supports html5 server-sent event? if not, is there a code or jquery needed to add SSE on IE?

I search everywhere and I can't find one. thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Searched everywhere, including the [IE feedback site?](http://connectbeta.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/797678/ie-support-of-html5s-server-sent-event)

Answer (score 1):

According to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/eventsource), no known version of IE (with 11 being the most recent at the time of writing) supports server sent events.

[Portal](http://flowersinthesand.github.io/portal/) claims to emulate support for server sent events back to IE6.